# Extract specific data from txt file

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking to track my poker tournament results.
The poker site I'm playing at saves .txt files with tournament data.
I would like to import specific data from the .txt file.

The files are built like this:

```
PokerStars Tournament #910967412, No Limit Hold'em
Buy-In: $200.00/$15.00 USD
1178 players
Total Prize Pool: $235600.00 USD 
Tournament started 2014/06/01 22:30:00 CET [2014/06/01 16:30:00 ET]

  1: 1_conor_b_1 (United Kingdom), still playing
  2: 1dönertasche (Germany), still playing
  3: 23noraB (Austria), still playing
  4: 2noll6 (Sweden), still playing
......
You finished in 97th place (eliminated at hand #116994480258).
```

I would like to extract this data:

- Tournament number (#)
- Buy in amount
- My finishing position (example: You finished in 97th place)

Is this possible without using VBA?

Over-course would be to save data from new txt files to an excel table.

Comment: I would expect it probably is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: The thing is I'm an intermidiate excel user at best. Hence I havn't figuered out were to start.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Regular Expressions (Regex):

```
tnumber:  \#(\d*),
buy in:  In:(.*) USD
Place: in (.*) place
```

[image]